# Extract elements in a nested list into separate lists according to the positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a nested list say :

```
[[1,2],
 [3,4],
 [5,6]]
```

How can I extract a column from this list, (either `[1,3,5]` or `[2,4,6]`) **without converting it** into a `pandas DataFrame` or an `np array` like :

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
list(pd.DataFrame(a)[0])
```

or

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
list(np.array(a)[:,0])
```

which both yields `[1,3,5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to unpack you lists as:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

list1, list2 = zip(*a)
```

`zip` returns an iterator of tuples, which are then unpacked into `list1` and `list2`, if you want lists, `map` to `list` and then unpack:

```
list1, list2 = map(list,zip(*a))
print(list1)
[1, 3, 5]
print(list2)
[2, 4, 6]
```

`zip` aggrates the elements from the input iterables. By unpacking with `zip(*a)`, we're making each inner list a separate iterable in in `zip`, which will then "combine" the elements in each of these according to their positions.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
col = 0
[item[col] for item in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `map` `function`.

```
y=list(map(lambda x:x[0],a))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you want `one-line list comprehension`:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

print([[elem[i] for elem in a] for i in range(len(a[0]))])
```

NOTE: `len(a[0])` is what I'm using , so this will work only for `inner-lists of equal lengths`.

Answer (score -1):

I am a beginner in python, could you please try this.

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
for i in a:
    print(i[0])
```