# How to create for loop for submatrix and print submatrix

Tags: python

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN95m.png)

I am trying to create for loop for submatrix, let say

```
matrix = [
    [1, 0, 1, 3],
    [0, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
]
```

I want to print submatrix from matrix[2][3] to matrix[4][4] where index start at 1.

Output what i expect -

```
    [2, 2]
    [3, 4]
    [3, 4]
```

Comment: You won't be able to have the index starts at 1 unless you create a specific function to handle this behaviour.

Comment: Is this `numpy` or `list` ?

Comment: @SayandipDutta List, Not Numpy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: slicing a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277100/python-slicing-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: Why don't you hard code the indices in the for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract elements in nested list into separate lists according to positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694894/extract-elements-in-nested-list-into-separate-lists-according-to-positions)

Comment: What attempt yielded this output?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a range for those coordinates, just keep in mind that list indexes in python are zero based and that `range`s are inclusive of the start index but exclusive of the end index:

```py
for row in range(2, 5):
    for col in range (3, 5):
       print(matrix[row - 1][col - 1], end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work

`print([x[2:] for x in matrix[1:]])`